# When does following error occurs "org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory"

Tags: java, linux, spring, oracle, apache

I am trying to connect to oracle DB from linux which gives me following exception:

> Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory

But for same connection string and driver version I am able to connect Oracle from windows.

Comment: maybe you have a network problem or your database server is stopped.

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with an ojdbc6.jar driver. I changed it to ojdbc14.jar it worked fine for me.
Oracle's official site shows ojdbc6.jar as the latest driver for oracle11g which doesn't work for me on Linux platform. 
You can download Ojdbc14.jar from the following link
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc-10201-088211.html